# How to bold certain parts of a UITextView

Tags: c#, xamarin

Assuming I have a UITextView that displays the text:

**E-mail**: jon.smith@test.com

How do I bold certain parts of a given UITextView (E-mail in this case)? I have bolded the whole UITextView with the following code:

```
customLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 20f);
```

But how do I bold certain sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [NSAttributedText](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/text_field/style_text/)

```
var bold = new UIStringAttributes {
    Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 20f)
};

var email = new NSMutableAttributedString ("E-mail: jon.smith@test.com");
email.SetAttributes (bold.Dictionary, new NSRange (0, 6));

customLabel.AttributedText = email;
```